# Can't call template function from helper function

Tags: c++

I am using a template function I found online which is meant to return the length of an array in C++. I have found that if I call the method directly it works however when I call it via another method I get the error `no instance of function template "array_size" matches the argument list`.

I have obviously misunderstood something about how to pass arrays through method but I'm stumped as to why this doesn't work.

```
template<size_t SIZE, class T> inline size_t array_size(T(&arr)[SIZE]) {
    return SIZE;
}
int wordLength(char* word) {
    return array_size(word) - 1; // Gets argument error
}
void fooBar() {
    int n = array_size("Hello"); // Works!
    int m = wordLength("Hello"); // What I want    }
```

What detail am I missing about this and how do I fix it such that I can call `wordLength`

Comment: It's simply not possible, because in the `wordLength` you don't have an array. All you have is a pointer, and there is no way to tell what data it points to or how much memory is allocated for that memory. If you want to get the length of a string at compile-time, you need to use `constexpr` arguments and `constexpr` recursive functions.

Comment: Does it work if you declare wordlength as `int wordLength(char word[])`

Comment: this template works only on arrays on compile time and you are trying to use it on pointer to char and during run-time. `wordLength` doesn't have a array length data in any form so it will never work. This is C++ so just use `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `array_size` works. It retrieves array length information from the type itself, so in case of `array_size("Hello")` the type of literal `"Hello"` is actually `const char[6]`. But when you use your function `wordLength`, you are erasing the length information from the type and it becomes just `char*`.

A direct way to fix your code would be to make `wordLength` a template:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
int wordLength(T (&word)[N]) {
    return array_size(word) - 1;
}
```

However, I suggest you not to actually do this. The better way would be to switch to `std::string` type, if you want to work with strings; to `std::array` if you want to work with stack-allocated fixed size arrays; or to `std::vector` if you want to work with dynamic arrays. There are almost no use cases for C-style arrays in C++ except for when working with external API, so I suggest you to avoid using them in your code.